# StatEt with R 2.15

Tags: r

Does anybody know if there is any (easy) way to make StatEt working with R 2.15? The current StatEt version is frozen to R 2.14 version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've used StatET with R2.15 for several months.

Answer (score 4):

I use the testing version of StatET 3.0 with RJ 1.1, which officially supports R 2.15. The [installation instructions](http://www.walware.de/it/statet/installation.mframe?jump=install-rj-rpkg) suggests StatET 2.0 officially supports R 2.12 - 2.14. The update site for StatET 3.0 is, depending on your version of Eclipse:

http://download.walware.de/eclipse-3.8/testing

http://download.walware.de/eclipse-3.7/testing

http://download.walware.de/eclipse-3.6/testing

StatET 3.0 requires rj and rj.gd version 1.1, which can be installed from within R:

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")
```

More details on StatET 3.0 are available in these two threads:

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2012-May/001408.html

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2012-February/001284.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a few issues with setting up StatET in Windows and wrote therefore a small blog-tutorial about it that might be of use, you can find it [here](http://gforge.se/2012/05/setting-up-statet-eclipse-in-windows/).

The setup is 64-bit Windows 7, R 2.15 64-bit & 64-bit Indigo Eclipse.